# Incrementing a variable in Java

Tags: java, andengine, counter, increment

I'm just beginning to get my feet wet with Java.

I need to increment a variable from 0 to 13 then when the variable reaches 13 then it needs to start decrementing all the way down to 0 again, and start all over again.

Here is my code:

```
(arriba = false){ 
   x++; 
   Log.d("incr", "x :" + x + " " + arriba); 
    if (x > 9){ 
      arriba = true; 
      if (arriba = true) { 
         --x; 
         if (x < 0) { 
          arriba = false; 
                    } 
               } 
         }
     }
```

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working for you?  We're not mind readers here.

Comment: [Try something.](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry about that here's what i've tried and it seems to count down but it doesn't count back up! `if (arriba = false){
        
        x++;
        Log.d("incr", "x :" + x + " " + arriba);
       
       if (x > 9){
        arriba = true;
        
       if (arriba = true) {
        --x;
        
        if (x < 0) {
         arriba = false;
        }
       }
       }}`

Comment: Please edit your question and the above code to it.

Comment: How is WallPaper and AndEngine related to your question then? can't you stay focus and be specific on the question?

Comment: I'd have a closer look at the [Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), in particular [The whole and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) and [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: guys bear with me, as i mentioned on the first post i'm new on this forum, can you just disregard the word wallpaper and andengine and answer the question?

Comment: Proper grammar goes a long way; capitalize "i", etc.

Comment: @user1705074 - Stack Overflow is not a forum. It's a Q&A site. There's a difference.

Answer (score 1):

the answer of A.R.S. is missing the decrement part.

```
int i = 0;
int delta = 1;

if (i == 0) {
  delta = 1;
}
if (i == 13) {
  delta = -1;
}

i += delta;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here too and people here don't usually code for you. You should try it yourself first, post the code you've made so that people will give suggestions or corrections to your code.

Anyway, a newbie programmer like me would do it like this:

```
int x = 0;
int i = 1;
while(true){
    // print x

    // if x is 13
        // i = -1
    // else if x is 0
        // i = 1;

    // add i to x
}
```

Comment: Ah i see, yeah i've tried different things but that was my mistake not putting what i've tried so far here, ok thanks for your input, let me try your code but i'm not sure it will do what i need to accomplish, basically i have the variable inside a timer which ticks every 200mS so the variable needs to start incrementing by 1 on every tick until it reaches 13, once it reaches 13 then it needs to start counting back down to 0, hope i'm making any sense!

Comment: You just remove the while loop and put the code inside your timer.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
for (int i=0; i<27; i++)
{
    int j = (i<14 ? i : 26-i);
    // j will go 0,1,2,3...12,13,12,11,...0
    // do something with j
    ....
}
```

or

```
for (int i=-13; i<14; i++)
{
    int j = 13 - Math.abs(i);
    ....
}
```

or... well you get the idea.

Comment: thanks this will work, i'm sorry again, i'm a visual basic programmer so you guys can imagine that to me Java is a whole different beast.

Comment: Ok this works, but how would i do if i need j to increase or decrease on every tick of the timer, the way it is right now is just a continuous loop which counts 0.1.2.......13,12,11.....